# addEventListener, вызывая функцию с аргументом, теряется родитель узла

Tags: javascript, функции, аргументы

```
<div class="parent">
  <a class="child" id="child">Child</a>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <a class="child2" id="child2">Child with argument</a>
</div>

child.addEventListener('click', Handling);
child2.addEventListener('click', Handling(3));

function Handling(arg) {
var _this = this;
  if (_this.parentElement) {
    alert(_this.parentElement);
  }
  else {alert("no parent, arg="+arg);}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/o7xf5j9s/

Если вызывать функцию Handling без аргумента, родитель возвращается. При попытке вызывать с аргументом он теряется.

Comment: У вас во втором хендлере undefined лежит так-то. Нажмёте на кнопку, получите ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае вы правильно устанавливаете функцию на клик. Во втором случае вы устанавливаете на клик результат этой функции, то есть `undefined`. Поэтому при попытке ее вызвать, вы получите `TypeError`. Хотите вызвать коллбек с аргументом, используйте `Handling.bind(child2, 3)`. Это создаст новую функцию с установленным в первом аргументе контекстом, а остальное - это как раз параметры вашей функции.

Comment: Omg, я и сам забыл, что в bind можно передавать не только this, но и аргументы, с которыми функция будет вызываться. Спасибо, действительно, хороший ответ